# many to many relation with nhibernate on the entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-many, hbm

I have a problem with nhibernate,

i have a hbm file with a many to many relations.
This works so far but i want to generate the hbm from a entity

and trying to set the properties on the entity but that will not compile

this is the hbm file

```
<list name="Category" table="Category" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="none">
  <key column="categoryId" />
  <index column="ordinal" />
  <many-to-many class="Product, Assembly" column="productId" />
</list>
```

and have did now on the entity

```
    [List(2, Name = "Product", Table = "Product", Cascade = CascadeStyle.None, Lazy = false, Fetch = CollectionFetchMode.Select)]
    [ManyToMany(5, ClassType = typeof(Product), Column = "productId")]
    public virtual IList<Category> Categorys
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the ordinal and the key on the entity
try this

```
    [List(1, Name = "Product", Table = "Product", Cascade = CascadeStyle.None, Lazy = false, Fetch = CollectionFetchMode.Select)]
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Key(2, Column = "categoryId")]
    [Index(3, Column = "ordinal")]
    [ManyToMany(4, ClassType = typeof(Product), Column = "productId")]
    public virtual IList<Category> Categorys
```